# Get rows in all levels with parentId SQL

Tags: sql-server-2012, rows, levels

I have a table `Categories`, and each row in this tables have a `parentId`. The parent is just an other row in the same table.

I want to create query to get all children in different levels by just giving the `Id` of the first Parent.

Comment: Any attempts of solving this yourself? Data samples? Table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With recursive cte:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( id INT, pid INT )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, NULL ),
        ( 2, NULL ),
        ( 3, 1 ),
        ( 4, 1 ),
        ( 5, 3 ),
        ( 6, 5 ),
        ( 7, 6 ),
        ( 8, 6 )

DECLARE @p INT = 1;

WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     @t
               WHERE    pid = @p
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   t.*
               FROM     @t t
                        JOIN cte c ON c.id = t.pid
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte c
```

Output:

```
id  pid
3   1
4   1
5   3
6   5
7   6
8   6
```

**EDIT:**

To use in another `select statement`:

```
WITH    cte
      AS ( SELECT   *
           FROM     @t
           WHERE    pid = @p
           UNION ALL
           SELECT   t.*
           FROM     @t t
                    JOIN cte c ON c.id = t.pid
         )
SELECT  *
FROM    cte c
JOIN AnotherTable t on c.id = t.id
```

Comment: if you use 3 as ParentId you have to get just the row with Id = 5 ?!!

Comment: No, 5 has it own childs 6 and 6 has childs 7, 8. Don't you want leaf childs?

Comment: @KernelMed, do you want all immediate childs or all leaf childs?

Comment: For example if i search with 1 i have to get 3,4 and the childs of 3 and the childs of 4  (in this example 5 is the child of 3 so i have to get it, and 5 is the parent of 6 so i have to get 6, and 6 is the parent of 7 and 8 so i have to get both 7 and 8)

Comment: @KernelMed, then it becomes even more easy. See my edited answer.

Comment: Yeeeeeees Thhhx for help

Comment: hi, i have an other question, if whant to use the result in an other select, for example, select *  from x where x.id in (the result of this select)

Comment: @KernelMed, you didn't even upvoted my answer and want me to answer your questions? If you have question, open new thread.